# Meteor.js, extend an object when publishing it

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I have **messages** collection.
Each message has an **userId**.
I also defined **displayUsername()** function, that gets the id of user, and returns **fullName**.

My question is can I extend it with underscorejs on the server. or what is pratical way to extend an Object

```
messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages");

Meteor.publish("messages", function () {
  var allMessages = messages.find({}).fetch();
  return _.each(allMessages, function (msg) {
    return _.extend(msg, {
      username: displayName(msg.userId)
    });
});
```

so I want

```
{{#each messages}}
  <p><strong>{{username}}:</strong> {{messageBody}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

I know, that it is possible on the client side, but I am going to use it some more time...

thanks..

Answer (score 2):

check transform on Collection.find

http://docs.meteor.com/#find

chris has a video tut talk about "Transforming Collection Documents"

The transform option on Meteor Collections allows us to transform MongoDB documents before they're returned in a fetch, findOne or find call, and before they are passed to observer callbacks. It lays the foundation for a Model layer. In this episode I'll build a simple transform class that has a formatPrice method for a price that is stored as cents in the database.

http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-transforming-collection-documents

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't send down a transformed collection. But you can transform it on the client side.

e.g when you define your collection on the client:

**client side js**

```
var messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages", {transform:function(doc) {
    doc.username = displayName(doc.userId);
    return doc;
}});
```