# How to deal with client Objects in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, leaflet

I've a little project [(housescrap)](http://pierreozoux.github.io/housescrap/). In this project the idea is the following :

- a database server side to serve houses details to the client
- users preferences about houses saved in the data store of their choice thou [NimbusBase](http://nimbusbase.com/)
- a local representation of the data set that mix both and handle the [LeafLet](http://leafletjs.com/) marker variables.

The little demo is made with a csv for the server side and an array for the client side.

I'm now working on a [real implementation](https://github.com/pierreozoux/housescrap/tree/meteor/meteor/house). I choose meteor to do so. I found it convenient for the subscription scheme (if a user moves the map, I update the subscription, and the user receive the delta.) (Maybe this choice is wrong, please tell me)

My question now would be, how can I build a class of houses with methods (like add, delete) , and object attributes(like LeafLet markers) that are a mix of meteor collection and other data within the meteor framework? If it is not possible, what would you recommend?

Thanks a lot for your help!

PS: I'm quiet new to web development with a bit of experience with rails development, so, sorry for misunderstanding of basics concepts.

Comment: Ok, I read [that](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) but still not answering my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in fact, the issue, is just how to extend Meteor Collection documents, and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333365/meteor-js-extend-an-object-when-publishing-it) already answer my doubts.

In term of code, it looks like this :

```
House = function (document) {
  _.extend(this, document);
};

_.extend(House.prototype, {
  addToMap: function () {
    console.log("added!");
  }
});

Houses = new Meteor.Collection("houses",{
    transform: function (document) {
      return new House(document);
    }
  }
);
```

And in the documentaion of meteor, it is [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection), in the transform section.

There is a good [video](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/YNiRTAfN38Ehf5Brn) explaining this idea.